# Elasticsearch: using mapping to index one field different ways

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
  "hosts": {
   "mappings": {
     "host": {
      "properties": {
        "dn": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "fqdn": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "hostname": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        .....
      }
    }
}
```

where my intention is to be able get exact matches on 'dn' and full text on 'fqdn'.  What happens in practice is that searches on 'dn' work fine but searches on 'fqdn' always return no documents.

E.g.

```
{"query": {"term": {"dn": "ps346256.uoa.auckland.ac.nz" } } }
```

returns one document but

```
{"query": {"match": {"fqdn": "ps346256" } } }
```

returned none.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fqdn` should be referenced as `dn.fqdn` as shown below:

```
{"query": {"match": {"dn.fqdn": "ps346256" } } }
```

Find the reference for multi-fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I had read that doc, multiple times!  Sigh...  The mapping now says fqdn: {type: 'keyword’, fields: { indexed: {type: 'text' } } } which works and explains how it works ;)